# How to install Remote Desktop Services on Azure VM without requiring an Azure domain?

Tags: azure, remote-desktop-services, entra-domain-services

It appears that in order to install Remote Desktop Services on an Azure Windows 2019 Server VM, the VM must be [joined to a domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm).  And it [appears](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-ds/) the Domain product is over $100USD per month for the lowest tier.

Is there any way around this?  I simply need to set up a *single* server to provide remote desktop access to a *single* app for about 5 people.  (Yes I know I must purchase RDP CALs.)
The cost of the Azure Domain Services is much more than the cost of a single tiny VM ($10/mo).  How can I keep the cost low?

Thanks for any advice on how to achieve this for a low cost, and simple deployment.

Comment: I simply installed Active Directory services on the same VM from Server Manager.  Duh, that was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create VM on azure portal and must be allow 3389 port in network. IF you create VM with the support of NSG then you have to enable also port in  3389 in network security group.

Comment: I did this, but when I try to install Remote Desktop Services, it fails without being joined to a domain.  I need RDS because I need more than 2 simultaneous RDP users.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to hack it if you're able to install only the Remote Desktop Session Host on a machine, but that isn't, to my knowledge, a supported configuration. I would strongly recommend against presenting a plain RDP server to the Internet with no additional security layers on top of it. Microsoft's solution for this is the RDS stack, which requires an AD to work. All in all, those additional $100/month do add a certain amount of value to the solution.